# Qt drive dropdownlist only usb stick

Tags: c++, qt, drop-down-menu, usb

I want a drop down list where the disks are displayed, but only usb sticks.

i use QtStorageInfo and I already see all the attached disks but I would like to show only USB sticks.

Here is my code:

app.cpp:

```
...
        app::app(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::app)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        ...
        connect(ui->pushButton_9, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &app::refresh);
        connect(ui->comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &app::update);
        refresh();
        update();
    }

    app::~app()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

void app::refresh()
{
    ui->comboBox->clear();

    for (auto volume : QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {
        ui->comboBox->addItem(volume.rootPath() + " " + volume.name() + " [" + QString::number(volume.bytesAvailable() / 1073741824) + tr(" GiB]"), QVariant(volume.rootPath()));
        }
    }
...
```

app.h:

```
...
    class app : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit app(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~app();
        void refresh();
        void update();
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly in Qt.

However, you can use Qt's function QStorageInfo::device() to obtain the device name,e.g. "/dev/sdb1". With that name, you can add operating system specific code to get further information about that device.

As a side note: Your requirement to show "only USB sticks" is badly phrased. It makes more sense to ask for removable storages. That would also include external USB hard drives, as well as SD cards.